# Choose multiply file and remove button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create multiple files upload option that allow user to click on icon and then to choose file to upload.

Every time the user clicks on the icon, a new  field is being added with type file and its name being the same as the file name.

I am able to upload multiple files. But I'm not able to delete them after the upload.

Here is my code:

```
 <input type='file' id='_file' multiple="multiple">
 <div id='files_list'>
 <ul></ul> 
 </div>

 <script>
  $("#_file").change (function () {
    var ele    = document.getElementById ('_file');
    var result = ele.files; 

    for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x ++) {
        var fle = result [x];

        $("#files_list ul").append (
            "<li class='list_item'>" + 
                fle.name +  
                "<span class='remove'>X</span>" + 
            "</li>"
        );        
    } 

    $(document).on ('click', '.remove', function () {
        var span_id = $(this.parentNode).text();
        $('.list_item' + span_id + '').remove ();
    });
 });
 </script>
```

Any idea on how to delete the files?

Comment: `append("<li id='list_item'>" `  duplicate ids are invalid.  use a class.  same with the removes.

Comment: Hi Taplar, First of all Thanks for your replay. I tried with class also but it's not working.

Comment: Your `li` class is just 'list_item'.  But you are trying to append some span to it.  That's not going to find anything.  All you have to do the find the li to remove is `$(this).closest('li').remove();`

Comment: Thank you so much Taplar. It's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input type='file' id='_file' multiple="multiple">
    <div id='files_list'>
      <ul></ul> 
   </div>
   <script>
   $("#_file").change (function () {
   var ele    = document.getElementById ('_file');
   var result = ele.files; 

   for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x ++) {
    var fle = result [x];

    $("#files_list ul").append (
        "<li class='list_item'>" + 
            fle.name +  
            "<span class='remove'>X</span>" + 
        "</li>"
    );        
  } 
  $(document).on ('click', '.remove', function () {
    var span_id = $(this.parentNode).text();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
 }); });
 </script>
```

Comment: Please elaborate *how* and * why* this solves the issue.

Comment: And while you're at it, please fix the code block. The last two lines do not show correctly.